# Command line developer tools missing after OSX update

Tags: macos, command-line, software-update

I have noticed that every time I do Mac OSX update the `Command line developer tools` is getting lost. I had to install it again after each OSX update. Is there a way to prevent this? Or Is there a way to automatically install it during OSX update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have fixed this on OSX El Capitan 10.11.4. I have just upgraded OSX and command line developer tools exists. I hope it will be fine on future updates too.